# como pasar un objeto 3d que tengo en escena adelante de un Image de la UI en unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity

quiero poner de fondo una imagen en mi juego pero tengo un objeto 3d en escena y la imagen lo tapa, como podria colocar adelante del fondo(Image de la UI) el objeto alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar la distancia de plano en el componente canvas si cambias el render mode a "screen space - camera".

[image: Componente Canvas]

Comment: Bro me ayudo eres un carck, gracias!!!!